# How can I edit this code by using XMLReader to run it correctly

Tags: java

var element = (Element) row;
String id = element.getAttribute("id");
float cost = Float.parseFloat(element.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0).getTextContent());
float downPayment = Float.parseFloat(element.getElementsByTagName("downPayment").item(0).getTextContent());
String state = element.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent();
float percentage = Float.parseFloat(element.getElementsByTagName("percentage").item(0).getTextContent());

```
    NodeList netIncomeNodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(" netIncome");
    float  netIncome = Float.parseFloat( netIncomeNodeList.item(0).getTextContent());

    var property = new Property();
    property.setId(id);
    property.setCost(cost);
    property.setDownPayment(downPayment);
    property.setState(state);
    property.setPercentage(percentage);
    property.setNetIncome(netIncome);
    System.out.println(property);
}
```

Comment: You mean how to format the XML ? if yes, there are multiple online option to format

Comment: Please format your code completely. Also show us the import area so we can see which XML reader you are using. Also, example data would be good and a description of the desired result!